# detect if function exists within the class and if not call a different function. PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns

I know there are other ways around this but just for the sake of simplicity I would like to know if its possible to do something like:

```
   MyFactory::Create()->callMe();
```

and myFactory class:

```
   class MyFactory {
       private $obj;

       public static Create() { 
           $this->obj = new ClassA();
           return $this->obj;
       }

       public function __undefinedFunctionCall() {
           //function does not exist within MyFactory Class but it exists
           // in ClassA
           $this->obj->callMe();
       }
   }
```

so basically the function **callMe** does not exist within MyFactory class but it exists in ClassA. Dont ask me why I cant just **extend** classA because the code structure is already written and its not up to me to modify it. I just need a way around it.

Comment: Looks like a case for [__call()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)

Comment: I think thats it inside __call I could check if function exists and if not try the function from other class. thanks Mark

Answer (score 5):

You could simply use [method_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)

It takes 2 parameters `method_exists ( mixed $object, string $method_name )`

The first is an object instance or a class name, and the second is The method name.

So it should be as simple as:

```
if(method_exists($this->obj,'callMe')){
   $this->obj->callMe();
}
else{
//...throw error do some logic
}
```

Comment: as I mentioned i do not want to do this check outside of class. Want my Factory class to detect any undefined function calls

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **Mark Baker** I found the solution. In case anyone else has similar problem the following solved it:

added this function inside my factory class

```
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
            //if function exists within this class call it
        if (method_exists(self, $name))
        {
            $this->$name($arguments);
        }
        else
        {
            //otherwise check if function exists in obj and call it
            if (method_exists($this->obj, $name))
            {
                $this->obj->$name($arguments);
            }
            else 
            {
                throw new \Exception('Undefined function call.');
            }          
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also notice that you can not use `$this` inside `static` Create method as you wrote in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To checks if the class method exists or not:

```
$this->obj = new ClassA();
var_dump(method_exists($this->obj,'callMe'));
```

if it is static method:

```
var_dump(method_exists('ClassA','callMe'));
```

Returns `true` if the method given by method_name has been defined for the given object, `false` otherwise.

[php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)

Comment: that I know but I want to detect it within class inside MyFactory and not outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your correct about using the Magic method __call(), but you are implementing it wrong.

1. You dont need to check if it exists on its own class, PHP does this internally for you. The magic method __call only happens if the method doesn't exist.
2. You are passing a single array argument to $this->obj->$name, where you should be passing in each argument separately.
3. Nothing gets returned.

This is how you should implement the __call magic method for your purpose.

```
public function __call($name, $arguments) {
    if(method_exists($this->obj,$name)) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->obj, $name), $arguments);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Undefined method ".get_class($this)."::".$name);
    }
}
```